# Magento 2.1 media queries not working

Tags: css, magento

I am extending the Luma theme and am using the default breakpoints in __responsive.less.
It seems that some breakpoints work and some just seem to get completely missed out.

My queries are as follows:

```
/**** 320 Mobile****/
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'max') and (@break = @screen__xxs){}

/**** 480 Mobile****/
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__xs){}

/**** 640 Mobile/ Tablet****/
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__s){}

/***768 Tablet****/.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__m){}

/****1024 DT****/.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__l){}

/****1440+****/.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__xl){}
```

I have added my @screen__x to the variables but I don’t see @break or @extremium in the __variables.less at all.
Does anyone know what these variables are exactly and if there are any issues with my media queries please let me know

Many thanks.